# How can I give my arrow direction and arrow color in asp.net coolgrid based on information from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

The arrow colour is given in the database field - "OverallStatusCd" and the arrow background colour is given in the database field- "OverallTrendCd".
CSS is written for arrows and background colour.
We can access these things using the code below by changing 'up', 'down', 'right', 'left' and colour is changed by changing 'green', 'red'

span id="sptrend" runat="server" class="arrow arrow-up-icon arrowgreen">/span

How can I use this dynamically based on the information from the database?
"OverallTrendCd" is giving 'R' for RED, 'Y' for YELLOW
"OverallStatusCd" is giving values 'Up', 'Down', etc...

Comment: How do you decide the arrow direction and bg colour? (which values map to direction and colour from db?) What language do you use? C#,VB?

Comment: Arrow direction from database field 'OverallStatusCd'.
Bg colour from database field 'OverallTrendCd'.

I use C# language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<span id="sptrend" runat="server" class='<%# String.Format(("{0}{1}"), Eval("OverallStatusCdClass"), Eval("OverallTrendCdClass "))%>'></span>
```

if you must inclue '`arrow`' or any other string other than in the DB that is hard coded then you can alter `String.Format(("{0}{1}"),` to be `String.Format(("arrow {0}{1}")`

Note: I assume that your span is in a databound control..

```
SELECT OverallStatusCd, OverallTrendCd, 
CASE WHEN OverallStatusCd = 'Up'  THEN 'up'
     WHEN OverallStatusCd = '.Down' THEN 'down'
END AS OverallStatusCdClass ,
CASE WHEN OverallTrendCd = 'R'  THEN 'red'
     WHEN OverallTrendCd = 'Y' THEN 'yellow'
END AS OverallTrendCdClass 
FROM    YourTable
```

For SqlDataSource it will be something like in an aspx page (to help you relate things in your mind extending my answer) :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <span id="sptrend" runat="server" class='<%# String.Format(("{0}{1}"), Eval("OverallStatusCdClass"), Eval("OverallTrendCdClass "))%>'></span>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT OverallStatusCd, OverallTrendCd, 
                CASE WHEN OverallStatusCd = 'Up'  THEN 'up'
                     WHEN OverallStatusCd = '.Down' THEN 'down'
                END AS OverallStatusCdClass ,
                CASE WHEN OverallTrendCd = 'R'  THEN 'red'
                     WHEN OverallTrendCd = 'Y' THEN 'yellow'
                END AS OverallTrendCdClass 
                FROM YourTable">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks #wooer .....
In DB the colour is given as R for RED, Y for YELLOW. But in code I need Red, Yellow, etc...
In DB direction is given as Up, Down... But I need it as 'up', 'down' ..etc...
How this can be possible?

Comment: That was the thing that I have asked in my above comment. Then you need to alter you SQL statement in your datasource if you provide you Select Statement I can provide you a better answer..

Comment: #Wooer.. I am not suppose to alter the SQL statement..
Without changing the database, any other solution is there..?

Comment: See my update to your select statement, this doesn't alter your DB, you will just add above Case statements to your select statement (and make the required changes accordingly) and leave anything else in place.. Just Try it.. It'll be alright..

Comment: Thanks very much Wooer, But Sorry if I am asking a foolish question..
The select statement you are telling is in the sql server, right...?
Can I get solution which I can apply on aspx page or aspx.cs page

Comment: How do you bind your databound control? if SqlDatasource then you'll need to alter its select statement.

Comment: Glad that I helped. In case my answer is what you were looking for then you should mark it as the accepted answer. Happy coding..