# Local JavaScript - write to local file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript code loaded from a local HTML file (without going through a webserver).. i.e., opened using `file://`

Is there a way the JavaScript code in this file can be used to write to a local file?

I know that cross-site restrictions do not allow lot of things in JavaScript, but this is not cross-site, so it should be allowed in theory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self modifying html-JavaScript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854059/self-modifying-html-javascript-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) that allows you to read and write to a local file.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. Is this plugin still available?

Answer (score 4):

In case of Internet Explorer you can use [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            function WriteToFile()
            {
               var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
               var txtFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\TestFile.txt", true);
               txtFile.WriteLine("This is a test");
               txtFile.Close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            <script type="text/javaScript">  WriteToFile(); </script>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the activeX idea is good but I need the page to work in Firefox too

Comment: Perhaps a firefox extension would do you some good. Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO

Comment: ActiveX? So it only works on Windows? What about the security implications?

Answer (score 0):

There's no native API* for File System access in browsers.  You need that first!

For example, in Internet Explorer, there's an ActiveX object for it:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

...but it requires the user to relax their browser settings.  On other browsers, you may be able to use a jar (Java Archive) file.

You could also see what non-browser JavaScript containers offer, e.g. Microsoft HTA files (HTML Application) will support the Windows ActiveX FileSystemObject fine, providing your Virus Checking Software allows HTA files to execute.

Comment: * APIs now exist, but good support is still lacking: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem