# How to update local json file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, post

How do I update local json file using angularjs. My file name is `data.json` which is location in project folder.

I tried this below way

```
var data = [{
  "Numbers": {
      "Number": {
          "_Id": "1",
          "__text": "201"
      }
  }
}];

var jsonFileName = "data.json"

factory.updateJsonDataByFileName = function (jsonFileName, data) {
    $http.post(jsonFileName, data).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var jsonResult = response.data;
        deferred.resolve(jsonResult);
    }, function errorCallback(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

My JSON File looks like this below

```
{
    "Numbers": {
        "Number": {
            "_Id": "1",
            "__text": "200"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message does the Developer Console show?

Comment: no error message...data is not updated.

Comment: There's no native API* for File System access in browsers. For more information, see [Local JavaScript - write to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349921/local-javascript-write-to-local-file).

Comment: Avoid the [deferred Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

Comment: There is no way to update local file. initiate JSON in local storage and update it with response data which is come from HTTP request. But if your trying to get dynamic data, use database and get data from HTTP request.